# How to inject IHttpClientFactory in Container servicestack.net?

Tags: servicestack

I'm working on a solution that interacts with Redis, using the servicestack.net library.
I have a class that inherits from ServiceStack.AppHostBase and asks me for an override of the Configure method. This method has as a parameter a Funq.Container that I see is an implementation of IServiceProvider, IResolver and IContainer, and none of these interfaces have the AddHttpClient method that is provided by the IServiceCollection. Method I need to be able to inject the IHttpClientFactory. Any idea how to solve my problem?

Answer (score 1):

To do it in ASP.NET (not .NET Core), the quick way would be to:

1. install `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` package and call `.AppHttpClient()` extension
2. Build the Service Provider you would normally see in .NET Core
3. Get the instance of `IHttpClientFactory` from the Service Provider
4. Register the instance of `IHttpClientFactory` with `Funq.Container` again

```cs
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

public class AppHost : AppHostBase
{
    public override void Configure(Container container)
    {
        ...

        RegisterHttpClientFactory(container);
    }

    private container RegisterHttpClientFactory(Container container)
    {
        var services = new ServiceCollection()
            .AddHttpClient();
        
        // You can kind of inspect services returned.
        // You can see this extension registers lot of other things too beside
        // IHttpClientFactory.
        // Also you can see the lifetime of IHttpClientFactory is Singleton.

        var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

        container.AddSingleton(serviceProvider.GetService<IHttpClientFactory>());

        return container;
    }
}
```

#### If you happen to use Unity Adaptor

Unity has a package to give you an extension as well to build the Service Provider directly into the Unity Container:

```cs
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Unity;
using Unity.Microsoft.DependencyInjection;

public static class UnityConfig
{
    public static void RegisterTypes(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        ...
        container.RegisterServices();
        container.RegisterHttpClientFactory();
    }

    private static IUnityContainer RegisterHttpClientFactory(
        this IUnityContainer unityContainer)
    {
        new ServiceCollection()
            .AddHttpClient()
            .BuildServiceProvider(unityContainer);

        return unityContainer;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the interface definition of `IServiceCollection` from [IServiceCollection.cs](https://github.com/aspnet/DependencyInjection/blob/master/src/DI.Abstractions/IServiceCollection.cs):

```
public interface IServiceCollection : IList<ServiceDescriptor>
{
}
```

`AddHttpClient` is just an [extension method](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Http/src/DependencyInjection/HttpClientFactoryServiceCollectionExtensions.cs) from **Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection** that wraps adding a number of additional dependencies to ASP.NET Core IOC.

So you should continue to register it on ASP.NET Core IOC, i.e:

```
public class Startup : ModularStartup
{
    public new void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddHttpClient();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseServiceStack(new AppHost
        {
            AppSettings = new NetCoreAppSettings(Configuration)
        });
    }
}
```

As any dependencies [registered .NET Core Startup are also available to ServiceStack](https://docs.servicestack.net/netcore#register-aspnet-core-dependencies-in-apphost).

Comment: What about registering it in ASP.NET, not .NET Core?